# Vídeos - En modales no muestra botón pantalla completa

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, video

Nos hemos encontrado con este problema.

Explico lo más detalladamente posible como estamos realizando un proyecto.

Tenemos una página de demostración, la llamamos demo, y otra en donde están todos los elementos por separado de toda la web, así para que a otros clientes les resulta más fácil construir la página "real", lo llamamos módulos.

Una vez aclarado esto, hemos incluido un vídeo en la página. Lo curioso, es que en los módulos, este vídeo muestra el botón de pantalla completa, pero en la demo no. Recalcar que estos vídeos se muestran en un `modal` de bootstrap. En los módulos simplemente hemos recreado un `modal` ya abierto, y puede ser este mismo modal de la demo lo que impide ver este control, aunque no estamos seguros.

Demo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Módulos
[image: Módulos]

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="ver-video">
        <video controls >
          <source src="video/video-finanzas.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="video/video-finanzas.ogv" type="video/ogv">
          <source src="video/video-finanzas.webm" type="video/webm">
            Tu navegador no soporta el video
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper-content">
        <img src="img/icn-step2-cercana.png">
        <h4>¡Casi aciertas!</h4>
        <h5>Texto</h5>
        <p>Más texto</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-onboarding" target="_top">Enlace</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-onboarding .ver-video {
    background-image: url("../img/Step2_Resposta.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
}
.modal-onboarding .ver-video video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Como comento, no entendemos por qué el botón desaparece. ¿Tal vez porque el modal de bootstrap lo elimina? Si es así, ¿hay alguna solución? El código HTML y CSS en ambas páginas es el mismo, copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, una etiqueta `video` de HTML5 en una etiqueta `frame` impide ver ese botón en Chrome y Firefox (exceptuando Safari). He realizado una prueba, y efectivamente, ocurre esto.